# How to style add input field from add in a form style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

i meet some issue with my html when i have added a input to my add click let me show you what in mean in the image below
[image]

The add and remove are there as i have created a new input when click on add and remove the new input when dont need it

Here my code for my input field and function

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="validationNumber" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact:</label> 
   <div class="col-4">
      <input id="validationNumber" name="phonenumber" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="\b\d{8}\b" required>
      <a onclick="add()"><label style="cursor: pointer;">Add</label></a>
      <a onclick="remove()">remove</a>
      <div id="new_chq"> 
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
         Enter a correct PhoneNumber!
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   $('.add').on('click', add);
   $('.remove').on('click', remove);
   
   function add() {
   var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val()) + 1;
   var new_input = "<div><input type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'pattern='^[0-9]{8}$' required><div class='invalid-feedback'>Enter a correct PhoneNumber!</div></div>";
   
   $('#new_chq').append(new_input);
   
   $('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no);
   }
   
   function remove() {
   var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();
   
   if (last_chq_no > 1) {
       $('#new_' + last_chq_no).remove();
       $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no - 1);
   }
   }
</script>
```

Now i wan is how can i style my add remove to the right of the contact: input box
and How can i make my new input not squeeze them together ?

Comment: Well, there is not styling on the dynamically created input, so it adopts a default width. You should `form-control` to its class list.

Comment: ah yea i forgot about it now how i can not make the input squeeze one and another 
updated the question a bit

Comment: Add some margins. Since you seem to be using Bootstrap, add the appropriate classes. If I remember, the classes for margin-bottom are `mb-*` where `*` is any integer. You could try `mb-1`

Comment: ah yes is fix :) with the space thanks added new question related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot this `class='form-control'`

You should change this line

```
var new_input = "<div><input type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'pattern='^[0-9]{8}$' required><div class='invalid-feedback'>Enter a correct PhoneNumber!</div></div>";
```

to this

```
var new_input = "<div><input type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'pattern='^[0-9]{8}$' class='form-control' required><div class='invalid-feedback'>Enter a correct PhoneNumber!</div></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks silly me now the next issue is how to separate the stick input

Comment: you can just add `style='margin-bottom:5px;'` with dynamic input

Comment: now how can i move my add to the same position as the input field and to the right ?? 
must i use position: fixed to do it ? I will ask this question in the next new question

Answer (score 0):

hope this could help you:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationNumber" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact:</label>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9 form-group">
                <input id="validationNumber" name="phonenumber" type="text" class="form-control " pattern="\b\d{8}\b" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-form-label">
                <a class="d-inline m-1" onclick="add()"><label style="cursor: pointer;">Add</label></a>

                <a class="d-inline m-1" onclick="remove()">remove</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-9" id="new_chq">
            </div>
        </div>


        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_chq">

    </div>
</div>
```

I changed ur js code a little too:

```
<script>
    $('.add').on('click', add);
    $('.remove').on('click', remove);

    function add() {
        var new_chq_no = parseInt($('#total_chq').val()) + 1;
        var new_input = "<input class='form-control mb-3' type='text' id='new_" + new_chq_no + "'pattern='^[0-9]{8}$' required><div id='newAlert_" + new_chq_no + "' class='invalid-feedback'>Enter a correct PhoneNumber!</div>";

        $('#new_chq').append(new_input);

        $('#total_chq').val(new_chq_no);
    }

    function remove() {
        var last_chq_no = $('#total_chq').val();

        if (last_chq_no > 1) {
            $('#new_' + last_chq_no).remove();
            $('#newAlert_' + last_chq_no).remove();
            $('#total_chq').val(last_chq_no - 1);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: We suggest you to add details about why your code will help the question and what you changed